# in python, how can i run concurrent generator loops that pause or terminate when one of them yields?

Tags: python, while-loop, concurrency, generator, simpy

i want to model the maintenace process on a piece of production equipment. this machine may be down for maintenace due to one of three reasons, namely (i) it may breakdown according to an exponentially distributed probability described by expovariate of 1/MTBF, where MTBF is the mean time between failures, (ii) or it may eventually become due for a time based service as per defined schedule, say after 4, 13, 26 or 52 weeks since the previous service, the servicing of which re-sets the breakdown probability to start all over again (iii) or it may be taken down for routine inspections and any arising repair or restoration works following the findings of the inspections, which again resets the breakdowns expovariate function. is it possible to set up three while True loops that will run their respective timeout functions concurrently but all stop as soon as any one of the three processes actually times out? preferably within the simpy environment? something like...

```
         
    import simpy
    import random

    mtbf = 150 #hours
    service_interval = 600 #hours
    inspect_repair_interval = 300 #hours


    def run_to_failure():
        while True:
            failed = random.expovariate(1/mtbf)
            yield env.timeout(failed)
        
    def run_to_service():
        while True:
            stopped = service_interval
            yield env.timeout(stopped)
        
    def run_to_repair():
        while True:
            paused = inspect_repair_interval
            yield env.timeout(paused)
```

now, how do i run all 3 functions concurrently but be able to stop and reset all once any one of them yields? the yielded value will serve as an input to subsequent processes, and which of those subsequent processes run also depends on which function yielded the value

Comment: one way is to use Environment.process without a yield to launch your three processes.  You will need to keep save the events environment.process creates in global variables so which ever process time outs first can cancel and restart the others.  The other way is to have only one loop that uses AnyOf to yield to the three events at the same time.  AnyOf will let you know with event finished first.  You will still need to deal with the other events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a example of a machine with three process running at the same time: the main machine task, a loop of regular maintenance, and breakdown events

```
"""
quick sim of a machine with breakdowns

programmer: Michael R. Gibbs
"""

import simpy
import random

class Machine():
    """
    A machine with a main processing loop that can be
    interupted with breakdowns
    """

    def __init__(self, env):
        """
        Initializes the machine and starts
        processing and breadowns
        """

        self.env = env

        # start main task
        self.startup()

        # start schedule for service
        self.service = self.env.process(self.wait_for_service())

    def startup(self):
        """
        Starts up the machine
        Also starts up the breakdown schedule
        """
        self.task = self.env.process(self.main_task())
        self.breakdown = self.env.process(self.wait_for_breakdown())

    def shut_down(self):
        """
        Shuts down the machine
        Also kills the pending breakdown
        """
        
        if self.task is not None:
            # only shutdown if not running
            self.task.interrupt()
            self.task = None


        if self.breakdown is not None:
            # only cancel pending breakdown if it is still pending
            self.breakdown.interrupt()

    def main_task(self):
        """
        The main processing loop of the machine
        """

        print(f'{self.env.now} - starting up machine')

        try:
            while True:
                yield self.env.timeout(3)
                print(f'{self.env.now} - did some work')
        except simpy.Interrupt as i:
            print(f'{self.env.now} - processing has been interupted')

        print(f'{self.env.now} - shutting down machine')

    def wait_for_service(self):
        """
        Schedules and executes maintaince 

        runs on a loop
        breakdowns do not delay maintenance schedule
        """
        while True:
            yield self.env.timeout(21)
            # time for maintenance
            print(f'{self.env.now} - time for service')

            if self.task is None:
                # already processing a breakdown
                print( "-------already shutdown ")

            else:
                self.shut_down()

                # do maintenance
                yield self.env.timeout(2)
                print(f'{self.env.now} - finished service')

                # restart machaine
                self.startup()

    def wait_for_breakdown(self):
        """
        Creates a one time breakdown
        """

        print(f'{self.env.now} - breakdow clock started')

        try:

            yield self.env.timeout(random.randint(4,10))
            # time for a breakdown

            self.breakdown = None

            print(f'{self.env.now} - breakdown')

            # shutdown and fix machine
            self.shut_down()

            yield self.env.timeout(7)

            # machine fixed, start it back up
            print(f'{self.env.now} - breakdow fixed')

            self.startup()
        except simpy.Interrupt as i:
            print(f'{self.env.now} - breakdow clock stopped')



env = simpy.Environment()
machine = Machine(env)
env.run(100)
```

Comment: excellent, gives me something to work with. for context, full scope of problem is: a facility has multiple machine types, say n (not fixed), each of which has 1 or more units, say m (also not fixed, & may vary between types). all machines send job requests to a central workshop from time to time, where they are resolved as per some priority criteria, e.g. b/down requests supersede service requests from other machines even if they joined requests' queue later. central resources are technicians (preemptive), workshop-tools (resource) and spare parts (container).

Comment: [continued]....aim is to collate and analyse data on queue delays/resources utilisation. will appreciate any further insights.